# How to remove downloaded source code aka External Sources in Visual Studio 2022 Debugging

Tags: debugging, open-source, visual-studio-2022, debug-symbols

I accidentally enabled downloading open source code.

I've disabled the "all modules" option in Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.

Now I want to know how to remove the symbols I've already downloaded?

[image]

Things I've tried

. Enable / disable Just my code

. Enable / disable source server support

. Enable / disable Source link support

. Load only specified modules

. Empty Symbol Cache

. Empty %LocalAppData%\SourceServer

. Clean solution

. Delete .vs folder for solution

. Restart machine

. Restart VS2022

Comment: Could you elaborate how you enabled downloading open source code, if it was enabled by you, maybe it’s an option in VS? If you click the dll files, can you see the path in the Properties Window? Looks like if you remove them, they will be downloaded again, automatically? Will [reset VS settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022#reset-settings) work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a way to turn External Sources off

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but I think this only disables the visual node and not the feature. VS still does stuff in the background.

Comment: I swear I never turned this on; it just appeared one day. Thanks for the info how to turn it off! Now all we need is a way to disable Script Documents.

Comment: How this suddenly just appeared I don't know. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I found to get rid of the External Sources was to do the reverse of the list at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugging-external-sources-with-visual-studio/#settings-required.

Then click the "Empty Symbol Cache" button on the Options -> Debugging -> Symbols panel

Comment: thanks man, you just saved many hours of mine